# Table with a relation datasource opening first item in datasource

Tags: google-app-maker, google-workspace

Im experiencing a problem where when I try to open a page of an item in a table, the first record in the datasource always opens first.

My setup. I have a page "SystemDetails" with the datasource "System", and a table within that page with a datasource "System:ActionItems"(relation). Within the table, I have a button for each row that when clicked, shows a different page "ActionItemDetails".

An example of my problem. Say I click in the table an item with Id #3,  the page "ActionItemDetails" shows, but the page's content loads with item Id #1. However, when I go back to the "System" page and retry clicking Id #3, it loads Id #3 as desired, and I am able to successfully open every item successfully.

This problem seems to only happen on the first time I open the "ActionItemDetails".

I thought this should be able to work natively in appmaker without any code, but I have also tried using selectKey and selectIndex in the edit button with no luck.

A side note. I also noticed that when the page "ActionItemDetails" first loads, there is only one item loaded when I console.dir(), so think the problem seems to be coming from not loading all the items.

Comment: Add and Enable `ActionItems` prefetch on datasource `System` query.